# Update statement that will update the "Active" field of an employee if the corresponding department is inactive

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update my employee's `Employee_Type`: if the `Department_Type` is `Inactive`, then the `Employee_Type` must be updated to also be `Inactive`.

This is my code I don't know why isn't working. There is primary key in `tblEmployees` which is `EmployeeID`, and there is a foreign key in `tblDepartment` which also `EmployeeID`:

```
UPDATE tblEmployees
SET Employee_Type = t2.Department_Type
FROM dbo.tblEmployees AS t1
RIGHT JOIN dbo.tblDepartment AS t2 ON t1.Employee_Type = t2.Department_Type
WHERE t2.EmployeeID = '6';
```

The result is:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

But nothing happens actually.

Answer (score 1):

Your written logic implies the following query:

```
UPDATE tblEmployees
SET Employee_Type = t2.Department_Type
FROM dbo.tblEmployees AS t1
RIGHT JOIN dbo.tblDepartment AS t2
    ON t1.Employee_Type = t2.Department_Type
WHERE
    t2.Department_Type = 'inactive'
 -- t2.EmployeeID = '6';    -- not sure about this requirement
```

I don't know why you were targeting a particular employee in the `WHERE` clause, but this is inconsistent with trying updated all employee types to inactive whose departments are also inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update t1
set t1.Employee_Type = t2.Department_Type
from dbo.tblEmployees as t1
right join dbo.tblDepartment as t2
on t1.Employee_Type = t2.Department_Type
where t2.Department_Type = 'InActive'
```

This will update all employee type to `InActive`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

```
UPDATE tblEmployees
SET Employee_Type = t2.Department_Type
FROM tblEmployees AS t1
LEFT JOIN tblDepartment AS t2
ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
WHERE
t2.Department_Type = 'Inactive'
```

Comment: This is identical to the query I posted an hour ago, except that you used `Inactive` with a capital first letter as opposed to `inactive`.  Without seeing any data, would you expect us to be able to guess what is inside your table?